# Convert dB value to linear scale

Tags: volume

Does anybody know the math required to convert a logarithmic decibel scale to a linear value between 0 and 1, for an automation lane?

In this particular case - the linear value 1 = +15dB, the linear value 0 = -∞dB.

Comment: 'Decibel' is a ratio, not an absolute value. To answer this we'd need to know the range of decibel values and the scale reference.

Comment: Ok so the unit delivering these values actually gives -32768 for the fader right down, but 0 when it is right up.  So when I have this value (call it N) it aligns exactly to the physical fader positions with this function (N / 10) + 10 - so that effectively gives the same value as shown on the fader which runs from +10dB down to - infinity with -60 the last number.  The scale seems logarithmic to me on the fader.

Comment: What is the automation lane to be used for?

Comment: @MarcW Volume on an audio track in a multi-track editor.  The scale runs from +15db to -15dB in side the multitrack editor.  In the session file which the multitrack editor loads, the value is stored as a linear point from 0 to 1 where 0.65 = 0dB, 0=-infinity dB and 1 = +15dB.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Practical version

- dB → gain-multiplier:

  > *g* = 2<sup>*d* / 6</sup>
- gain-multiplier → dB:

  > *d* = 6 · log<sub>2</sub>(*g*)

I find these definitions far more handy than the ones below: changing the amplitude by a factor of two is quite an intuitively relevant change. But, alas, in pre-computer times people couldn't seem to like logarithms of bases other than ten, so...

#### Official definition

- dB → gain-multiplier:

  > *g* = 10<sup>*d* / 20</sup>
- gain-multiplier → dB:

  > *d* = 20 · log<sub>10</sub>(*g*)

IMO base-10 is silly, but if you need to do exact calibrations, better use the official version. (Alternatively, use the base-2 version, but replace 6 with the factor 20 · log<sub>10</sub>2 ≈ 6.020599913; this is then exactly equivalent to the base-10 definition.)

Answer (score 1):

So if we set that 0 dB gain is 1.0 factor, and -∞ db gain is 0.0 factor, it means that (if we are considering voltage gain as in a mixing desk fader) :

gain = 20.0*log10(factor)

therefore :

factor = 10^(gain/20.0)

If, as described in a comment, the 0 dB gain is at 0.65 factor, it means the ref is 0.65.

gain in db = 20*log10(factor/0.65)

factor = 0.65*10^(gain/20.0)

Comment: How does this change if +15 dB gain is 1.0 factor and -∞ db gain is 0.0 factor?

Comment: @JamesHarcourt: just add / remove 15 from the dB scale.

Comment: @leftaroundabout that definitely doesn't work, the values that come out aren't anywhere near the linear values produced, i.e. 0dB = 0.65.

Comment: @JamesHarcourt er, no! 10⁽⁰⁻¹⁵⁾’²⁰ ≈ 0.1778. What did you calculate?

Comment: The application in question is Adobe Audition.  Their volume automation is stored in XML, so when there is an automation point of 0dB, it is shown thus: <parameterKeyframe sampleOffset="95176" type="linear" value="0.65" />.  So I actually want 0.65!

Comment: @JamesHarcourt: either this is _not_ a linear scale, or +15 dB does not correspond to 100%. I'd guess that in fact ~ +3 dB corresponds to 100%. +15 dB may be the _maximum possible_ setting, but it corresponds to 400% (which isn't implausible, sometimes you need such settings). Why they would choose +3 dB? That probably has something to do with stereo-panning compensation.